# Semantic issues showed up on QT Creator 4.7.0

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-creator

After updating Qt Creator from 4.6.0 (built on mar 27 2018) to 4.7.0 (built on july 17 2018), several semantic issues showed up.

For example, the code below will be fine.

```
//main
QObject::connect(&p1,   SIGNAL(mysignal),    &p2, SLOT(myslot)),      Qt::QueuedConnection) ||

// other file.hpp
class p2: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    /// Contructor
    explicit p2(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    /// Destructor
    virtual ~p2();

...
    };
```

But, if I add a QQueue to p2:
QQueue<*Type not important here*> my_queue;

Then this error will appear at the connect line.

```
error: no matching for call to connect
```

For the moment, I rolled back my QT installation and the issue is gone.

Comment: July 17th, 2018 is just recently. May be, it is better to post this issue as bug-report to `qt.io` instead.

Comment: Do you use precompile_header config switch in your .pro file?

Comment: I have opened a ticket a while ago and someone today just said that what you just proposed works: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-20855

Comment: He, that is me :-) I asked to check if it was the same reason for you :-)